# Tree parameters in ngx-datatable?

Tags: angular, tree, frontend, ngx-datatable

I am trying to implement [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) within my project and need to use the [tree provided](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#client-tree). However, I don't understand what are the roles of the two inputs required by the component (treeFromRelation, treeToRelation).
For example, given this source:

```js
export interface EmployeeExample {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  company: string;
  age: number;
  manager?: string;
}

const columns = [
  {
    fieldName: 'name',
    name: 'Name'
  },
  {
    fieldName: 'gender',
    name: 'Gender'
  },
  {
    fieldName: 'age',
    name: 'Age'
  },
  {
    fieldName: 'company',
    name: 'Company'
  },
  {
    fieldName: 'manager',
    name: 'Manager'
  }
];

const source: EmployeeExample[] = [
  {
    "name": "Ethel Price",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "Johnson and Partners",
    "age": 22
  },
  {
    "name": "Claudine Neal",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "Sealoud",
    "age": 55
  },
  {
    "name": "Beryl Rice",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "Velity",
    "age": 67
  },
  {
    "name": "Wilder Gonzales",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "Geekko",
    "age": 26
  },
  {
    "name": "Georgina Schultz",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "Suretech",
    "age": 22
  },
  {
    "name": "Carroll Buchanan",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "Ecosys",
    "age": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "Valarie Atkinson",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "Hopeli",
    "age": 50
  },
  {
    "name": "Schroeder Mathews",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "Polarium",
    "manager": "Ethel Price",
    "age": 42
  },
  {
    "name": "Lynda Mendoza",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "Dogspa",
    "manager": "Georgina Schultz",
    "age": 35
  }
];
```

In my component:

```html
<ngx-datatable #grid class="material expandable" [rows]="source" [loadingIndicator]="loading" [count]="totalElements"
  [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="70" rowHeight="auto" [reorderable]="true"
  [swapColumns]="false" [limit]="paging.pageSize" [offset]="paging.pageIndex" [externalSorting]="externalOperations"
  [externalPaging]="isRemote" [treeFromRelation]="'manager'" [treeToRelation]="'name'" (page)="setPage($event)"
  (sort)="onSort($event)" (treeAction)="onTreeAction($event)">
```

Using 'name' as value of treeToRelation input, it works. But when I try to use other properties, such as 'gender' it doesn't work properly: in this case it duplicates some entry and it doesn't show the others.

How can I fix it? Can someone explain to me the inputs roles?